# UI performance about Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

With fragment, it seems that, I can use one activity with many fragments to finish complicate UI.

Someone told me that one activity should not include more than 100 views regarding UI performance, now I want to know is there any performance limitation, such as I have ten fragments, one fragment include about 100 views.

BTW, I am developing an app for tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a set number of views at which your application stops functioning. The 100 views thing is just a rule of thumb. Don't prematurely optimize. Test on a few devices including a slowish one, and if it feels fine, then it's fine.