# Android Non-UI fragment

Tags: android, fragment

Recently,when I developed android app,I check the official document,it state a fragment which allow not to supply UI,so I want't to ask whether I can use a non-UI fragment to do something,because I don't know that if I add a fragment,it cost a lot cpu time or memory?Is it a inefficient behavior?

Answer (score 2):

May be you want to know about performance of fragment.

check this

[UI performance about Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176680/ui-performance-about-fragment?rq=1)

or Read this:-
http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/68/Fragments%20for%20All%20Presentation.pdf

Comment: For this fragment you do not need to create any fragment or framelayout in xml file

Comment: I want to know the performance of adding a fragment,because I want to decide whether it is valueable to add a non-ui fragment,just want to use its advantage of communication with activity

Answer (score 1):

Fragments are an excellent way to provide a lightweight service or maintain some state in your application. You can do without them, bundling everything into your Activity, but this gets unwieldy fast for a non-trivial application. Fragments are lighter-weight than splitting you app into multiple activities (though that can have its own advantages).

See also the responses to [What is the use case for a Fragment with no UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531648/what-is-the-use-case-for-a-fragment-with-no-ui).